# Display grid in custom admin module only when i enter id and click search button in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

i have created a custom module in admin panel which will display data from the DB it is working. but i want to display that grid only after you enter a id in the search box. i have not created the search box. can some one help me with search box creation on top a grid?